# iOS Safari - prevent input field from highlighting when selected

Tags: ios, safari

When tapping an input field in iOS the field will briefly hilight with a gray colour. Is there a way to disable or suppress this hilighting effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="textbox" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);">
```